# Custom Flex/ActionScript UIComponent Keeps Getting Painted Multiple Times During a Resize

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

I've created a custom uicomponent and whenever the browser or its specific container is resized, a repaint occurs but the contents of the component get drawn again and again and again...
So, if I move the container I'll end up with multiple circles drawn on top of each other but offset depending upon where the container is when the repaint occurs.
My updateDisplayList code is below.
Do I need to do some sort of clear so that it doesn't contiuously getting duplicated like this???
Thanks so much for any help!

```
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);                             

            trace("height: " + parent.height);
            trace("width: " + parent.width);

            if (parent.height <= parent.width) {
                radius = Math.round((parent.height*.95)/2);
            }
            else {
                radius = Math.round((parent.width*.95)/2);
            }

            trace("radius: " + radius);

            outterRadius = Math.round(radius*.70);
            innerRadius = Math.round(radius*.30);

            trace("outterradius: " + outterRadius); 
            trace("innerradius: " + innerRadius);

            centerX = this.width/2;
            centerY = this.height/2;

            trace("centerX: " + centerX);
            trace("centerY: " + centerY);

            var innerCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var outterCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var baseCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();

            baseCircle.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            baseCircle.graphics.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius);               

            outterCircle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, .75);
            outterCircle.graphics.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, outterRadius);


            innerCircle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, .75);
            innerCircle.graphics.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, innerRadius);

            addChild(baseCircle);   
            addChild(outterCircle);
            addChild(innerCircle);

            for (var bubbleCount:int=0; bubbleCount < bubbleList.length; bubbleCount++) {
                var globalPoint:Point = this.localToGlobal(getPointInCircle(radius));
                var radarBubble:RadarBubble = bubbleList.getItemAt(bubbleCount) as RadarBubble;
                var bubbleLocalPoint:Point = radarBubble.globalToLocal(globalPoint);
                radarBubble.x = bubbleLocalPoint.x;
                radarBubble.y = bubbleLocalPoint.y;
                trace("Add bubble: " + radarBubble.x + ", " + radarBubble.y + ", " + radarBubble.radius);
                addChild(radarBubble);                                      
            }                           

            // create radar display lines to be animated
            for (var angleCount:int=0; angleCount < 360; angleCount++) {
                var tmpLine3:Sprite = new Sprite();
                tmpLine3.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, 1);
                tmpLine3.graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);                                         
                tmpLine3.graphics.lineTo(getEndpoint(angleCount).x, getEndpoint(angleCount).y);
                tmpLine3.visible = false;
                addChild(tmpLine3);
                lineCollection.addItemAt(tmpLine3, angleCount);                             
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the [Flex component lifecycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html).  A lot of things may execute invalidateDisplayList() thereby causing updateDisplayList to be re-execute during the next render event.

The problem I see here is that you are creating new baseCircle, outerCircle, and innerCircle each time.  Rather, you should be creating one of each instance and updating it when updateDisplayList() runs.

I'd probably make your instances of innerCircle, outerCircle, and baseCircle variables on the current component.  In createChildren() you can add them as children on the component.  In updateDisplayList you can do the relevant drawing.

Comment: Thanks Guys - I'll read up on this a bit more to get a better understanding of updateDisplayList() and createChildren().  I'll let you guys know how I make out.  I don't even think I need the circles to be children, I can just draw those in the updateDisplayList().  But, the other children I'm adding need to be separate Sprites...

Comment: Flextras and Wade - when I add my lines that need to be animated within createChildren() using addChild(...), the lines never get displayed.  Initially they are set to visible = false b/c I have a timer that displays just one line at a time to animate the line.  any thoughts?

Comment: override protected function createChildren():void {
   super.createChildren();
   // create radar display lines to be animated
   for (var angleCount:int=0; angleCount < 360; angleCount++) {
    var tmpLine3:Sprite = new Sprite();
    tmpLine3.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xA10303, 1);
    tmpLine3.graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);              
    tmpLine3.graphics.lineTo(getEndpoint(angleCount).x, getEndpoint(angleCount).y);
    tmpLine3.visible = false;
    addChild(tmpLine3);
    lineCollection.addItemAt(tmpLine3, angleCount);        
   }   
  }

Comment: Ignore last code snippet.  I understand why I'm not seeing the children and that's because my child lines are being drawn with zeros for start and endpoint.   Maybe it would be easier to explain what I'm trying to do and see if you guys have any suggestions.  I want the updateDisplayList to draw this target/radar-like background and that works fine. However, I need to dynamically add and remove other children to this component and I can't seem to see any children that are added to this component unless I do it inside updateDisplayList.

Comment: when moving to reusing DisplayObjects, don't forget to call `graphics.clear()` in your redraw cycle for any DisplayObject you want to completely redraw. without calling `clear()` you'll just be appending lines/fills to the current graphics display,

Comment: Based on the feedback, I was able to gain a decent understanding of the UIComponent life cycle.   I now don't add any children within updateDisplayList and I just use the graphics object to draw the background image etc...  Thanks for the help!